# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState in RxJava subscription

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have following code:

```
 private void doLogin(String username, String password) {
    authManager.userLogout();
    subscribe(authManager.login(username, password)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> showProgress(R.string.authenticating_label, true))
            .subscribe(userObject -> {
                showProgress(false);
                if (userObject != null ) {
                    loginSuccess(userObject.loginName, userObject.password, userObject.authToken);
                } else {
                    loginFailed(username, password, null);
                }
            }, throwable -> {
                Timber.d(throwable, "Error while Login!");
                showProgress(false);
                loginFailed(username, password, null);
            })
    );

}
```

The loginFailed method performs simple DialogFragment show:

```
android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show
```

Unfortunatelly I can see that on some Android 8.0 and 8.1 devices there is an exception thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1842)
```

```html
29Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
30at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1842)
31at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1860)
32at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:650)
33at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:609)
34at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:205)
35at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismiss(DialogFragment.java:171)
36at com.cubesoft.zenfolio.browser.activity.BaseActivity.showProgressInternal(BaseActivity.java:205)
37at com.cubesoft.zenfolio.browser.activity.BaseActivity.showProgress(BaseActivity.java:199)
38at com.cubesoft.zenfolio.browser.activity.BaseActivity.showProgress(BaseActivity.java:194)
39at com.cubesoft.zenfolio.browser.activity.LoginActivity.lambda$doLogin$7(LoginActivity.java:200)
40at com.cubesoft.zenfolio.browser.activity.LoginActivity.access$lambda$7(Unknown Source:0)
41at com.cubesoft.zenfolio.browser.activity.LoginActivity$$Lambda$8.call(Unknown Source:8)
```

From what I can see, the state of Activity is not loss (we are not in pause/resume/onActivityResult state). 
What may be the reason?

Comment: maybe full stacktrace might be helpful

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Comment: Added stacktrace

Comment: Can you try using [`DialogFragment#dismissAllowingStateLoss`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#dismissAllowingStateLoss()) to dismiss the dialog?